# How to move typed text inside the input element?

Tags: html, css, input, text, padding

I made some input boxes with 0 20px padding placeholders. However the text I type inside ignores padding and starts from the exact left side (from the left outline). Is there any possibility to position it inside the input field?

HTML:

```
<div class="input-border">
    <label for="sign-login"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></label>
    <input type="text" name="sign-login" placeholder="Enter your Email">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input::placeholder {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: $font-base;
    color: #979797;
    padding: 0 20px;
    height: 38px;
}

.input-border {
    width: 340px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
}
```

I'd like the text I type to start from the same place as my placeholder is
in this case with 0 20px padding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

target the input text input[type=text]{padding:0 20px;}

```css
input::placeholder{
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: $font-base;
    color: #979797;
    padding: 0 20px;
    height: 38px;}
  .input-border
    form .input-container .input-border {
    width: 340px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
    border-radius: 0.5em;}
    input[type=text]{padding:0 20px;}
```

```html
<div class="input-border">
     <label for="sign-login"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></label>
     <input type="text" name="sign-login" placeholder="Enter your Email">
    </div>
```

Comment: So easy! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.center {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: the person asking the question already is using a placeholder text, so i doubt that that at least will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to add padding to the placeholder.

```
input::placeholder {
    padding: 0 20px;
}
```

Use this to add padding to input text.

```
input {
    padding: 0 20px;
}
```